# How float data type is stored in memory?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

If we create one variable of data type float and assign any value to it then how this is stored in memory?

`float var = 13.34;`

Comment: Who knows? It may not even be stored in memory.

Comment: What do you mean "how"?

Comment: Very often they are stored in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 format. But it depends on architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float is a 4-byte size type, which consist of sign, exponent and mantissa (described in IEEE 754). The last bit represents sign, 8 followed bits are exponent and rest are mantissa.

Comment: The C++ language definition does not require any of this. IEEE-754 is by far the most common representation for floating-point types, but there are others that have different properties.

Comment: @PeteBecker this answer described the most widespread implementation, which OP very likely will come across. I can't see a reason to elaborate the rest since effortless question worths only effortless answers